# How Do I Find a Gap In a Sequence in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of items with an id and a number_col. There are plenty of questions on Stackoverflow for finding gaps in IDs, but what I'm looking for is a gap in the number. For example, if I have 3 items:

```
id | number_col
===============
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 4
```

I need a SQL query that returns id = 1, number_col = 3 as missing. The query should look at the max value in number_col for each id. Since 4 is the max number_col value for id 1 in my example, it should not return that 1, 5 is missing.

Comment: not going to write this out for you... but start with a query that returns id's where the count of rows does not equal the max number_col value.  then for those, use a LEAD function to look for the next number and check if it is the current number +1.

Comment: http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-gap-analysis-missing-values-sequence.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want ranges of missing values, then:

```
select number_col + 1 as first_missing, (next_nc - 1) as last_missing
from (select t.*, lead(number_col) over (partition by id order by number_col) as next_nc
      from t
     ) t
where next_nc <> number_col + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this query

```
select * 
from table_name 
where col_name - 1 NOT IN (select col_name from table_name) 
GROUP BY col_name having col_name > MIN(col_name);
```

`GROUP BY col_name having col_name > MIN(col_name)` to discard the first row.