# Find first n 'unused values' in postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are a lot of questions and answers about either finding the [first 'gap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-do-i-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql) or the beginning and ending of [a gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789880/how-do-i-find-a-gap-in-a-sequence-in-postgresql).

I do not want that. I want to return the first n unused values.

Eg: Suppose I have a table `slots`:

```
slot_id | slot
--------------
1       | 2
2       | 4
3       | 5
4       | 7
```

The first 5 unused values are 0,1,3,6,8

How would I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest method is to generate all the values and choose the ones that don't exist:

```
select gs.slot
from generate_series(0, 8) gs(slot)
where not exists (select 1
                  from slots s
                  where s.slot = gs.slot
                 )
order by gs.slot
limit 5;
```

EDIT:

If you want to guarantee that you get at least 5 back, you can use:

```
select gs.slot
from (select generate_series(0, max(slot) + 5) as slot
      from slots 
     ) gs
where not exists (select 1
                  from slots s
                  where s.slot = gs.slot
                 )
order by gs.slot
limit 5;
```

Comment: this is awesome and it works great for my use case since I know the upper limit of how many slots I can have (about 100).
I'm still going to wait to see other answers that do not assume an upper limit. Thanks!